# setting Rails content-security policies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-security-policy

the following browser console error message is invoked many times on a given page

```
Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following  
Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' https:".  
Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-1eLkOKTGLdFR92ElIWA31YdS/7E3GLP3GvnXjSvRz+s='),  
or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.  
Note that hashes do not apply to event handlers, style attributes and  
javascript: navigations unless the 'unsafe-hashes' keyword is present.
```

refers to issues in in initializer which is set at stock values, plus a reference to an ngrok address for local development purposes

```
 Rails.application.configure do
   config.content_security_policy do |policy|
     policy.default_src :self, :https, 'https://343e-5-170-92-35.eu.ngrok.io'
     policy.font_src    :self, :https, :data
     policy.img_src     :self, :https, :data
     policy.object_src  :none
     policy.script_src  :self, :https
     policy.style_src   :self, :https
   end
   config.content_security_policy_nonce_generator = ->(request) { request.session.id.to_s }
   config.content_security_policy_nonce_directives = %w(script-src)
 end
```

These directives and their mechanisms are rather opaque to this user... and it feels particularly pointless when regarding inline styles, when sourced from self... adding `, :unsafe_inline` to th style_src policy does remove them but I fail to understand how an inline style would be considered `unsafe` if generated by `self` .